# Command line based interaction with the UCSC genome browser, automated data upload and track generation

Tags: ucsc, genome-browser

Is there a way to submit data to ucsc genome browser for result/track display, on the fly, as a local bedgraph file with example contents like below:

```
browser position chr19:49302001-49304701
browser hide all
browser pack refGene encodeRegions
browser full altGraph
#   300 base wide bar graph, autoScale is on by default == graphing
#   limits will dynamically change to always show full range of data
#   in viewing window, priority = 20 positions this as the second graph
#   Note, zero-relative, half-open coordinate system in use for bedGraph format
track type=bedGraph name="BedGraph Format" description="BedGraph format" visibility=full color=200,100,0 altColor=0,100,200 priority=20
chr19 49302000 49302300 -1.0
chr19 49302300 49302600 -0.75
chr19 49302600 49302900 -0.50
chr19 49302900 49303200 -0.25
chr19 49303200 49303500 0.0
chr19 49303500 49303800 0.25
chr19 49303800 49304100 0.50
chr19 49304100 49304400 0.75
chr19 49304400 49304700 1.00
```

Normally, you can input the data in the data box like below:

[image]

and submit - and display results after another [GO] button that's pushed manually on the following web page to produce the output below:

[image]

I am hoping there is a command line option for this where it takes the data input above as a local file name and generates the output that normally one can generate with a few manual clicks (including pasting of the data text into the window or upload of the data file) on the ucsc web page.

Thanks in advance